# Firebase authentication - Cloud Firestore - users collection - web modular v9

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a simple mechanism for authenticated users using `Firebase Authentication`. then I would like to create a collection `users` with a document referring `userID` of the authenticated user using `Firebase Cloud Firestore`.

Here is the code. -- with a bit of TypeScript, I'm using NextJS as framework but I don't think it really matters for the question:

```js
const clientCredentials = {
...
};

const firebaseApp = initializeApp(clientCredentials);
const firestore = getFirestore(firebaseApp);

interface SignUpFormValues {
  username?: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

export const createUser = (signUpValues: SignUpFormValues): Promise<any> => {
  const auth = getAuth();
  const { email, password, username } = signUpValues;

  return createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
    .then((userCredential: UserCredential) => {
      const { uid } = userCredential.user;

      const userRef = { username };
      return setDoc(doc(firestore, "users", uid), userRef, { merge: true });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // error handling flow
      throw error;
    });
};
```

As it is, everything is working fine **but** I'm not satisfied with the result at all.

i.e, if there is an error while setting a up a new document for my `users` collection, but the authentication part went well, and I try to invoke the `createUser` again, it will fail as the user is already created and authenticated.

Now I also have a listener setup somewhere else in a code, that check if the current user if authenticated or not.

Same here, straightforward code.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    // Listen authenticated user
    const auth = getAuth(firebaseApp);
    const unsubscriber = onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (user) => {
      try {
        if (user) {
          // User is signed in.
          const { uid, displayName, email } = user;

          // In theory I could setup the document here.
          setUser({ uid, displayName, email });
        } else setUser(null);
      } catch (error) {
        // Most probably a connection error. Handle appropriately.
      } finally {
        setLoadingUser(false);
      }
    });

    // Unsubscribe auth listener on unmount
    return () => unsubscriber();
  }, []);
```

I could potentially creating the user collection here, but it feels kinda wrong because I cannot do `if (doc(users/${uid}).exists()) createNewUserCollection()`. Instead I have to do `setDoc`, with `{ merge: true }` option.

My question is double:

- Is there an official way of handling this somewhat common use-case?
- Could I use a mechanism that "rollback" my authenticated user if the creation of the user collection did not work in the first place?

Any other suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an official way of handling this somewhat common use-case?

No it is not possible to combine in one atomic transaction the user creation in the Auth service and the doc creation in Firestore

> Could I use a mechanism that "rollback" my authenticated user if the
> creation of the user collection did not work in the first place?

You could [schedule a Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) that regularly checks that the users lists in the two services are in sync. If not, from the CF you can very well [delete](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users?hl=en#delete_a_user) from the Auth service the users that are not in the Firestore collection.

Comment: What would you personally recommend? Maybe I'm overthinking it.

Comment: Desynchronisation of the two lists is very rare according to my personal experience (Actually I never encountered it in any of my customer projects in the last 7 years). If you want to be 100% protected against this very low likelihood risk, running a Cloud Function is the solution IMHO.